# Why left join is not giving distinct result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following sql query and my left join is not giving me distinct result please help me to trace out.

```
       SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Position.Date,
                    Position.SecurityId,
                    Position.PurchaseLotId,
                    Position.InPosition,
                    ISNULL(ClosingPrice.Bid, Position.Mark) AS  Mark
        FROM
                Fireball_Reporting.dbo.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing POSITION WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED)
                LEFT JOIN Fireball.dbo.AdditionalSecurityPrice ClosingPrice WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) ON
                            ClosingPrice.SecurityID = Position.PricingSecurityID AND
                            ClosingPrice.Date = Position.Date AND
                            ClosingPrice.SecurityPriceSourceID = @SourceID AND
                            ClosingPrice.PortfolioID IN (5,6)  

 WHERE
        DatePurchased > @NewPositionDate AND
        Position.Date = @CurrentPositionDate AND
        InPosition = 1 AND

        Position.PortfolioId IN ( 
                                SELECT 
                                    PARAM 
                                FROM 
                                    Fireball_Reporting.dbo.ParseMultiValuedParameter(@PortfolioId, ',') 
                                ) AND
        (
        Position > 1 OR
        Position < - 1
        )
```

Now here in above my when I use LEFT JOIN `ISNULL(ClosingPrice.Bid, Position.Mark) AS  Mark` and LEFT JOIN it is giving me more no of records with mutiple portfolio ids 
for e.g . (5,6)

If i put portfolioID =5  giving result as `120 records`

If i put portfolioID =6  giving result as `20 records`

When I put portfolioID = (5,6) it should give me `140 records` 
but it is  giving result as `350 records` which is wrong .  :(

It is happening because when I use LEFT JOIN there is no condition of PurchaseLotID in that as table  `Fireball.dbo.AdditionalSecurityPrice ClosingPrice` not having column `PurchaseLotID` so it is giving me other records also whoes having same purchaseLotID's with diferent prices .

But I dont want that records

> How can I eliminate those records ?

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows?

Comment: Although you have used `DISTINCT` in `DailyLoanAndCashPosition` the same 20 values for `PurchaseLotId` that are in `NAVImpact` must appear in 70 different rows in `DailyLoanAndCashPosition`, differences in other columns make the 70 rows unique still.

Comment: it is showing me duplicate records for same purchaselotid , but we are doing inner join , then why it is taking duplicate records ? what could be solution ? please help

Comment: inner join does not eliminate duplicates, only records where there is no matching values. If you want to eliminate duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @DigitalD thanks but I have already used DISTINCT then also it is giving me duplicates :(

Comment: Can you share a few rows of "duplicates"?

Comment: Updated question with duplicate records ..

Comment: Those are not duplicate records. The `PurchaseYield` column is different between the two rows.

Comment: But when I give portfolioId =  5 it is giving me only one record not 2  :( and when i provide porfolioID  = 5,6 it is giving 2 records like above :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the left join produces duplicated PurchaseLotIds. The best way to know if if you perform a select distinct(PurchaseLotId) on your left side of the inner join.

Comment: That should list 70 different PurchaseLotIds

Comment: it is showing me duplicate records for same purchaselotid , but we are doing inner join , then why it is taking duplicate records ? what could be solution ? please help

Comment: The left join is the subquery producing duplicated PurchaseLotIds, the second is not (since you're grouping by that column). You should work around the first join, trying to produce unique PurchaseLotIds. I'll take a look to the query, so I can give you a hint.

Comment: please help in that `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Does the AdditionalSecurityPrice table have a PurchaseLotId column? If not, please post a list of the columns of that table.

Comment: AdditionalSecurityPrice table not having PurchaseLotID :( columns are follows :

`AdditionalSecurityPriceID` `Date` `PortfolioID` `SecurityID` `SecurityType` `SecurityPriceSourceID` `Bid` `Ask``

Comment: For what we know so far, the problem is that some records on the table at the left side of the LEFT JOIN match more than one record on the table at the right side of the LEFT JOIN. So, what

Comment: For what we know so far, the problem is that some records on the table at the left side of the LEFT JOIN match more than one record on the table at the right side of the LEFT JOIN. So, what you need to do is add a group by clause on the table at the right side, that should look like: **GROUP BY SecurityID,Date,SecurityPriceSourceID,PortfolioID**

Comment: Could you please show it to me on my above question query please but that select query does not contain any aggregation function :(
How can I use group by on that ?.

Comment: What I meant is that you should replace
    LEFT JOIN Fireball.dbo.AdditionalSecurityPrice ClosingPrice WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) ON
for
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SecurityID,Date,SecurityPriceSourceID,PortfolioID,Bid FROM Fireball.dbo.AdditionalSecurityPrice WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) GROUP BY SecurityID,Date,SecurityPriceSourceID,PortfolioID,Bid) ClosingPrice
    ON
    ClosingPrice.SecurityID = Position.PricingSecurityID AND
    ClosingPrice.Date = Position.Date AND
    ClosingPrice.SecurityPriceSourceID = @SourceID AND
    ClosingPrice.PortfolioID IN (5,6)

Comment: ok thanks but i'm not getting one thing very strongly that is when i give any one PortfolioId like 5 or 6 then why it is not giving me such multiple records ? why giving only  when i gave 5&6 ? :( any clue ? please

Comment: You say that when you filter records with portfolioId=5 you get 120 results and 20 when filtering by portofolioId=6, and when using the set of values (5,6) you get 350 instead of 140 (what I'd expect, also). That's pretty weird, I don't think of you as a fool, but make sure you're executing that queries with the same filter criteria, because if you are, you are in presence of a big problem. If so, try googling about a bug on your DBMS concerning this problem. Another thing you can try is compare queries results and find what records don't belong or are missing.

Comment: all conditions are same :( 
only when I submit multiple portfolios I used this function which seperate out portfolio ids 
as i shown in question 
 Position.PortfolioId IN ( 
                                SELECT 
                                    PARAM 
                                FROM 
                                    Fireball_Reporting.dbo.ParseMultiValuedParameter(@PortfolioId, ',') 
                                )
but works fine giving me output as (5,6) then also why getting more records :(

Answer (score 3):

You get one Entry per `DailyLoanAndCashPosition.PurchaseLotId = NAVImpact.PurchaseLotId`

which would mean you must have more entrys in with the same PurchaseLotId

Comment: yes it is showing me duplicate records for same purchaselotid , but we are doing inner join , then why it is taking duplicate records ? what could be solution ? please help